# Selenium code can not catch the table from Chrome

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to parse from

https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

and doing as the following, I get attribute error and the table variable remains empty, what is the reason ?

I use Chrome 80. Are the tags right ?

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser") 
table = html.find("table",class_="table table-bordered table-hover main_table_countries dataTable no-footer") #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever I have `table` tags, I find it easier to use `pandas` to capture the table.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
table = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(table)
        Country,Other  TotalCases  ... Tot Cases/1M pop  Tot Deaths/1M pop
0               China       81093  ...            56.00                2.0
1               Italy       63927  ...          1057.00              101.0
2                 USA       43734  ...           132.00                2.0
3               Spain       35136  ...           751.00               49.0
4             Germany       29056  ...           347.00                1.0
..                ...         ...  ...              ...                ...
192           Somalia           1  ...             0.06                NaN
193             Syria           1  ...             0.06                NaN
194       Timor-Leste           1  ...             0.80                NaN
195  Turks and Caicos           1  ...            26.00                NaN
196            Total:      378782  ...            48.60                2.1
[197 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: really ? you mean : No Selenium ??

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. If the end goal is getting the table data then yes, it is as simple as that.

Comment: ok, generally yes, I want to obtain the numerical information on the web. what else could be done through Selenium that Pandas can't ?

Comment: I use Selenium for anything that means navigation and interaction with the page (clicks, input text etc.).  `pandas` is an easy way of extracting *only* table data from the webpage. Anything else - BeautifulSoup or Selenium via `.text`, `.get_property()` etc. I won't expand further as a lot can be personal preference/opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much, shall you help on how to extract data each time the data is updated ? like if I set it to run each 15 minutes ?

Comment: Look up how to schedule your `.py`script to run at regular intervals. There are many solutions, and again, it's a case of personal preference which one you choose. I use `cron` jobs as my system runs Linux. Happy to try and help if you get stuck on anything specific.

Comment: Thank you so much,  I appreciate your opinions and help. I use Windows, I am not sure if it's applicable, but if so, I would like to learn it

Comment: Just one more thing, I noticed the values I download from the table with your code, are not the live numbers that I see on the website, but exactly the previous update. How is that possible ? and how to change it to the most recent ?

Comment: Ah, table index 0 (not 1) should give you the latest figures - updated answer.

Comment: Amazing ! so you mean that changing that index,  I can also access the older updated data ?

Comment: It seems it can be only 0 and 1 , I was willing to have access to all of the past data

Comment: please check my other question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60840568/dealing-with-non-float-numbers-and-nan-values-from-tables-when-parsing-dynamical/60840615#60840615