# Dealing with non float numbers and Nan values from tables when parsing dynamically from a website

Tags: python, pandas

How do I deal with nan values in a table from a website that updates periodically and some table values sometimes get nan

I am talking about coronavirus website table of cases.
I am having problem in the for loop :this is the error

> ```
> if '+' in table.loc[k,'NewCases'] and table.loc[k,'NewCases'] is not 'nan' :
> ```
>
> TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())

import pandas as pd 

def dateformat(t):

    data = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[t]})

    data['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y:%M:%D').dt.date
    data['Hours'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y:%M:%D').dt.time
    return data['Dates'],data['Hours']
    return 
i=1
times=[],dates=[]
while True:

    t=datetime.now()
    date,hour= dateformat(t)
    times.append(hour)
    dates.append(date)
    url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
    table = pd.read_html(url)[1]
    row2ad=[];
    for k in table.index:

        if '+' in table.loc[k,'NewCases'] and table.loc[k,'NewCases'] is not 'nan' :
            c= table.loc[k,'NewCases']
    #        dfcycles.loc[k,'NewCases']=1e3*int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, c)))
            c1=re.findall('\d*\.?\d+',c)
            table.loc[k,'NewCases']=float(c1[0])
            row2ad.append(table.loc[k,'NewCases'])
        elif table.loc[k,'NewCases'] is  'nan' and i==1:
            c= table.loc[k,'NewCases']

            table.loc[k,'NewCases']=0
            row2ad.append(table.loc[k,'NewCases'])

        elif table.loc[k,'NewCases'] is  'nan' and i!=1:



            time.sleep(600)
```

Apart from the above error: what I need to do is to get all the values in the table, remove the + from the numbers, also to keep the nan values that appear in some cells in some website updates, but I need to replace them with the previously exsisting value, but so far a good strategy did not come to my mind how this is possible in a dynamic update from the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to get you started. Do this after you read the dataframe:

```
cols=['NewCases','NewDeaths']
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('+',''))
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(',',''))
    df[col] = df[col].replace('nan','')
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col])
```

'NewCases' and 'NewDeaths' are the columns you need to preprocess. So for each, I am replacing '+', ',' and 'nan' with ''. Then converting them to numeric type.

If you can explain what you need to do further, I might be able to help.

EDIT:
[fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) fills, in your case, any `NaN`s with values from a different dataframe(df1), df and df1 having the same structure/size. In your case df1 would be a previously fetched set of data.

```
df=df.fillna(df1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! well, I want to parse each time there are new data, and store all the data over a certain time table, let's say 24 hours. then to make a plot of each column with respect to the time I save each time I scrapped the data. to make these plots meaningful, I should replace the nan variables in all columns with their previous existing value in that cell given that sometimes some cells are not updated and are nan

Comment: fillna doesn't drop rows, it fills nulls with a value of your choice. Please note that I updated the answer to replace 'nan' with '' (null).

Comment: Thank you for your amazing help! one thing, so in each cycle, I would store the df, then make the code sleep for some time and then will get the new df. if I want to keep all the data, I might need a stock dataframe that I append all of these right ?

Comment: Glad it helped. It might be better to save the dataframe into a .csv file whenever you fetch the data from the website (lookup `pd.to_csv` and `pd.read_csv`). That way you have a complete track of what data you have collected and you can refer back to old dataframes when looking to fill nulls.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to fix this problem is to change:

```
 if '+' in table.loc[k,'NewCases'] and table.loc[k,'NewCases'] is not 'nan' :
```

to

```
 if '+' in table.loc[k,'NewCases'].fillna('') and table.loc[k,'NewCases'] is not 'nan':
```

That way Nan values are cast to a string.

It's not the prettiest solution because it may ignore other edge cases (like an actual float being passed), but it should solve your immediate problem.

Comment: In this solution, `and table.loc[k,'NewCases'] is not 'nan'` is redundant because 'nan'  does not contain `+`.

Comment: Thank you  , you could also include the pretties solution ? cause I wanted to even replace the NAN to some value , like the previous existing value, to be able to have a plot over the whole time

Comment: It gave me     if '+' in table.loc[k,'NewCases'].fillna('') and table.loc[k,'NewCases'] is not 'nan':

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fillna'

Comment: I removed the redundant part, but the code gets stuck now even before arriving to the row with nan